# How do you make a wallpaper texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want a tan wallpaper with small blue polka dots, something "ugly". How could i make something like that for a texture?

Trying to make the wallpaper on the left.

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and upload images that illustrate what you want to do.See [How to upload an image 
to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: @susu ok i added what I'm trying to do, I haven't tried anything because i have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `Texture Paint` workspace and do the following:

1. Create a new texture by pressing on `+ New` button near the top.
2. Choose what ever settings you like.
3. Draw your texture of choice. Press `N` to see properties. Or right-click to get brush settings quickly.
4. After you are done go to the `Shading` workspace.
5. Select the object you want this texture on.
6. Choose a material for this object.
7. Create a image texture node. `shift + a >> Texture >> Image Texture`
8. Click on the `Image Texture` file drop-down. And choose the texture you made.
9. Connect the `Color` to `Base Color`.
10. Done!

Note: To view your changes in real-time as you are creating the texture you could do steps `4`-`9` right after you create your texture(before `3`)